# Can I get access to Amazon's AWS API?

Tags: webservices

Has anyone tried accessing the [Amazon web services (AWS) API](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) from *Mathematica*? I'm assuming the HTTP WebService module of *Mathematica* would be a starting point. Any suggestions on getting started would be welcome. The following [example from the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/WebServices/tutorial/AmazonExample.html) is not working:

```
Needs /@ {"WebServices`", "JLink`"};
InstallService[
  "http://soap.amazon.com/schemas3/AmazonWebServices.wsdl"];
```

> ```
>   InvokeServiceOperation::httpcode: 404 (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found) >>
> ```

Comment: [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/WebServices/tutorial/AmazonExample.html) is probably the wrong end of the Amazon, but it could be a start.

Comment: It seems that a number of Web Services in the Mathematica documentation are deprecated. In particular, the Amazon example leads to a 404 error. It would be great to have examples that actually work.

Comment: The link goes to Amazon API Gateway, which is a service within AWS, not an API in itself. It is unclear what API you want to access.

Comment: @C.E. I think fundamentally the question is how to do the auth process which is something called AWS4, per the single answer. On the other hand a more fleshed out client a la the ``OAuthClient` `` and ``KeyClient` `` packages would be more useful if it were built into the ServiceConnect framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can get started using the following code.  It currently connects to the AWS SES service but should be easily extended.[Git Hub](https://github.com/semdinsp/aws)

Comment: For completeness, can you give a short demonstration of the code you linked to?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!